# Sql 2008 export table csv with headers and data

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, query, export

I need to export a table in SQL Server 2008 with headers and data delimited with | ( pipes ), but some information inside of this table have , ( comma ) and CR or LR, it's possible to put it a "" in that?

I try to export with Export tool provide by SQL Server but don't have the option to put "" in that.

Answer (score 0):

The option was "Text Qualifier". In the export data option, set the "Text Qualifier" to ".